# Remove string after match along with the word/string after that

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut

I have a file containing lines of following pattern.

```
date=2020-02-22 time=13:32:41 type=text subtype=text ip=1.2.3.4 country="China" service="foo"  id=47291 msg="foo: bar.baz," value=50
date=2020-03-17 time=11:49:54 type=text subtype=anothertext ip=1.2.3.5 country="Russian Federation" service="bar"  id=47324 msg="foo: bar.baz," value=30
date=2020-03-30 time=16:29:24 type=text subtype=someothertext ip=1.2.3.6 country="Korea, Republic of" service="grault, garply"  id=47448 msg="foo: bar.baz," value=60
```

I'd like to remove type, subtype and service alongwith the value of those fields(value after =).

Desired output:

```
date=2020-02-22 time=13:32:41 ip=1.2.3.4 country="China" id=47291 msg="foo: bar.baz," value=50
date=2020-03-17 time=11:49:54 ip=1.2.3.5 country="Russian Federation" id=47324 msg="foo: bar.baz," value=30
date=2020-03-30 time=16:29:24 ip=1.2.3.6 country="Korea, Republic of" id=47448 msg="foo: bar.baz," value=60
```

I have been trying, with the little know, using `cut`, `awk`, `sed` but still not any near to solution. I've searched online for hours but that's gone in vain too. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something you might want to reuse or build on later:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split(s,tmp)
    for (i in tmp) {
        skip[tmp[i]]
    }
    FPAT = "[^ ]+(=\"[^\"]+\")?"
}
{
    c=0
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        tag = gensub(/=.*/,"",1,$i)
        if ( !(tag in skip) ) {
            printf "%s%s", (c++ ? OFS : ""), $i
        }
    }
    print ""
}

$ awk -v s='type subtype service' -f tst.awk file
date=2020-02-22 time=13:32:41 ip=1.2.3.4 country="China" id=47291 msg="foo: bar.baz," value=50
date=2020-03-17 time=11:49:54 ip=1.2.3.5 country="Russian Federation" id=47324 msg="foo: bar.baz," value=30
date=2020-03-30 time=16:29:24 ip=1.2.3.6 country="Korea, Republic of" id=47448 msg="foo: bar.baz," value=60
```

The above uses GNU awk for FPAT and gensub().

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/(^|[[:blank:]]+)(subtype|type|service)=[^[:blank:]]+//g' file
```

```
date=2020-02-22 time=13:32:41 ip=1.2.3.4 country="China"  id=47291 msg="foo: bar.baz," value=50
date=2020-03-17 time=11:49:54 ip=1.2.3.5 country="Russian Federation"  id=47324 msg="foo: bar.baz," value=30
date=2020-03-30 time=16:29:24 ip=1.2.3.6 country="Korea, Republic of" garply"  id=47448 msg="foo: bar.baz," value=60
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
awk -F " " '{ $3=""; $4=""; $5="";  print}' file
```

you're basically settings columns to an empty string.